# Unable to read data from the transport connection exception

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I've got a MySQL 5.5 DB server, using Entity Framework 4.3, MySQL Connector 6.5.4.

The problem that I'm seeing is that over a slow connection (~192kbs) seems to be fairly consistent.

The scenario is that I first call a method that looks like this:

```
using (var db = new IceCreamEntities(ConnectionString, null, null, null, "infinite timeout"))
{
   db.desserts.Add(myDessert);
   db.SaveChanges()

   db.dessertData.Add(new dessertBlob() { DessertId = myDessert.Id, Data = someData });
}
```

and then I call closely after that (say, within 30 seconds or so) a method to get that back.  It looks like:

```
using (var db = new IceCreamEntities(ConnectionString, null, null, null, "infinite timeout"))
{
   var myDessertData = db.dessertData.Where(m => m.DessertId == myId).FirstOrDefault();
   return myDessertData;
}
```

Now, the `IceCreamEntities` constructor call there that I'm using does the following:

```
public IceCreamEntities(string connectionString, string unused2, string unused3, string unused4, string forLongRunningStuff)
: base(connectionString)
{
   var objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
   objectContext.CommandTimeout = 0;
}
```

*(there are a couple other constructors that are used with different timeouts, but that is probably not germane to the discussion)*

The blob I'm putting into that dessertData table is about 3 megabytes in size.

When I'm not on a slow connection, I don't see this problem.

The exception I get is:

> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while
>   executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>
> ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered during command execution.
>
> ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.
>
> ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed.
>   ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host.
>
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 size)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at
>   MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.HandleOrRethrowException(Exception
>   e)
>
> at MySql.Data.Common.MyNetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count)
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.TimedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count)
>
> at System.IO.BufferedStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32
>   count)
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream,
>   Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.FetchDataRow(Int32
>   statementId, Int32 columns)
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.FetchDataRow(Int32 statementId,
>   Int32 columns)
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.GetNextRow()
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet..ctor(Driver d, Int32
>   statementId, Int32 numCols)
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId,
>   Boolean force)
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
>
> at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>
> at
>   MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>
> at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>
> at
>   System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
>
> at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)
>
> at
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source)
>
> at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)
>
> at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1
>   source)
>
> at IceCream.Repository.GetDessertData(Int64 dessertId) in ....

One other data point - I can call the method that does the add twice in a row with the same sized blob and I don't get this error (or the equivalent).  It only happens when I do an Add and then follow it up with the Retrieve.

Any ideas how to address this?  I had thought that settting the command timeout value to 0 would solve my problems but it doesn't.

**Edit**

One other point is that I did the math and 3 megabytes at 192mbs should take somewhere in the neighborhood of 128 seconds to transfer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after much searching and reading, I adjusted the following values in the my.ini file:

> **net_read_timeout**
>
> **net_write_timeout**

By setting those to the value **99999** and restarting my db server, I'm able to now retrieve that 3M file over the slow connection without further incident.

Comment: The installation directory.  Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-file-location.html

Comment: I only have MYSQL Connector Net 6.5.4 and 
MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE folders inside MySQL folder. Do you know where I can find a similar setting? I'm having the exact same issue and I need to set the net_read_timeout. atm I'm lost though

Comment: This is on the server itself.  Mine, for instance is found in **Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5**   So wherever your MySQL server is installed is where the ini file will be.

Comment: You can also modify this programmatically:

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("set net_write_timeout=99999; set net_read_timeout=99999", con );
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();